# When someone forgets to enter their username on the sign up page, prompt them to enter it rather than throwing an error

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, openid, sign-up

If you happen to pick one of the icons under "More sign up options" (other than Yahoo, that is), a new prompt appears asking for a username:

[image: Sign up with AOL]

If, for some reason, you don't put anything in that box and push either the "Sign Up" or "Submit" buttons, you get this cryptic error:

[image: OpenIdIdentifierRequired]

Instead, the user should get a popup such as:

[image: Username cannot be empty.]

Comment: related: [Why is the HandleSuccess method such a terrible one?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207390/165773)

Comment: I'm knee-deep in login right now, will take care of this in 6-8 weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, we were not properly converting the error type to the corresponding error message like we were supposed to. So, starting with the next build, we'll show a more coherent error message:

[image]