# The Stack Exchange Data Explorer reports an error on Line 0

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

In the fix I wrote for [Include a line number when there's a syntax error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239624)

I tried to handle both regular errors and errors that come with an Line number:

```js
if (response.line) {
    msg = 'Line ' + response.line + ': ' + response.error;
} else {
    msg = response.error;
}
```

Today I experienced this unexpected result:

> Line 0: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Is the `Line 0:` of any use for this type of error? I'm not even sure if you would be able to trigger that error halfway down your script.

If y'all agree this is useless,  shall we fix that?