# Can't finish registration in Stackoverflow.ru

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, user-accounts, unregistered-users

I have an account on Stack Overflow and also on Russian Stack Overflow. I can ask questions on Russian Stack Overflow, but it always displays the phrase "Finish registration". I have tried logging in by different methods — Facebook, Google, etc. — but it still says that my registration is not finished. Can someone help me with it? or explain what I should do there to finish the registration?

P.S: I can't write questions in Meta Russian Stack Overflow because it says that my registration is not finished.

P.S.S:
I have already tried "Click the "register" link at the top of the page." it brings to the login page with the phrase "Finish signing up by using any of the following options:". I have already tried all options there.
I also can't merge them because they already linked.

[image]

Comment: I have already tried "Click the "register" link at the top of the page." it brings to the login page with the phrase "Finish signing up by using any of the following options:". I have already tried all options there.

Comment: Also it's not a different accounts, so I can't merge them because they are already linked.

Comment: hmm... OK, guess SE developer should have a look then. Will vote to reopen, in the meanwhile you better add a screenshot of the login page with the error message. Edit: I [pinged a Community Moderator of the site in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29863646#29863646), hopefully he'll have a look as well

Comment: There is no error message, it's just infinite loop. I click on the registration Button, or Facebook or gmail and then get in the my account, where it says that I'm not register, when I click "Finish registration" I go to the LogIn page again.

Comment: Yes, something is weird here. You better obscure your email in the screenshot, unless you don't care anyone can now see it? :)

Comment: This is also handled on [ru.SO meta site](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3089/cant-finish-the-registration-in-stackoverflow-ru).

Comment: somewhat related: [Why is the HandleSuccess method such a terrible one?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207388/165773)

Answer (score 7):

You did nothing wrong. :) Something went out of sync on our end and your Stack Overflow на русском profile still showed up as unregistered. I fixed it up for you, so you should be all set.

If anyone runs into this issue in the future, please use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link found in the footer of each site and describe the problem. The ticket will then be forwarded to an engineer.

Comment: I have same problem on main Stack Overflow. I see "complete sign up" after authorization by click on "complete sign up". Can I start force sync somehow?

Comment: @lllyct You should be all set now.