# Complete Sign Up problem on Stack Overflow Portuguese

Tags: bug

I have same problem of this [Linked Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279597/cant-finish-registration-in-stackoverflow-ru/279685#279685?newreg=e7e83c5875064810a1361abef337c015), but I can't comment that because don't have reputation.

Comment: use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link found at the footer of each site and describe your problem there. It needs a dev to solve, nothing we can do.

Comment: I've added my comment to the accepted answer so this now qualifies as a dupe of that one.